# Getting ID of item from database, when item from ListView is clicked

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm new in android,in my app I need to get id from database when I click on listview item and the I use this id to retrive data from database in second activity. But I can't get id from listview
(Listview is in Main Activity)

My MainActivity -to display data in a listview from my database

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageButton btnadd;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
DatabaseOpenHelper databaseHelper;
TextView yekuntxt;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        final List<String> costumer_data = databaseAccess.getData();
        databaseAccess.close();
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, costumer_data);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                {
                   View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.arrayadapter,null);

                    String Id = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    Intent i =new Intent(test.this, activity_daxilet.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID", position);
                    startActivity(i);

                }

            }
        });
```

My Database access

```
public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}

public List<String> getData() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT AD,SOYAD FROM costumer_data", null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        list.add(cursor.getString(0)+ " " + cursor.getString(1));

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
```

My second activity

```
public class activity_daxilet extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView ad,medaxil,mexaric;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_daxilet);



    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle !=null){
        ad.setText("@position");
    }

}
```

Comment: In your SELECT statement you don't fetch the id so you don't store it anywhere in your adapter. How do you expect to find the id by clicking the list?

Comment: @mTak so, I shuld select id too but not show it right? but afterwards how can I get it from listview?

Comment: see the last parameter passed to `onItemClick` method and use `SimpleCursorAdapter` - that's it - you dont have to use any `List<String> costumer_data` and `getData()` at all

Comment: @pskink now I'm trying to change them to    SimpleCursorAdapter     but because of I'm new I have some difficulties, thanks for your response

Answer (score 1):

Using the 3rd parameter position for a ListAdapter will not equate to the id, especially if rows have been deleted.

The easiest way is to utilise a Cursor Adapter in which case the id will be the 4th parameter passed to the `onItemClickListener`. The `SimpleCursorAdapter` may well suffice.

To convert to using a SimpleCursorAdapter then :-

1. Add a method to your DatabaseAccess.java to return a Cursor (or replace the getData method) e.g.

:-

```
public Cursor getDataAsCursor() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{"AD","SOYAD","rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID};
    return this.database.query(
            "costumer_data",
            columns,
            null,null,null,null,null
    );
}
```

- Note it's not clear if you have defined an id column or what it's name is. A Cursor adapter requires a column named **_id**, *(`BaseColumns._ID` resolves to **`_id`**)*, hence the usage above.

  - The query convenience method has been used rather than the rawQuery method, although it may appear more complex, it is recommended over rawQuery.

.

2. FOR TESTING add a method to DatabaseAccess.java allow data to be added

:-

```
public long addRow(String ad, String soyad) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("AD",ad);
    cv.put("SOYAD",soyad);
    return this.database.insert("costumer_data",null,cv);
}
```

- Note this may not be required if you already have data or have an equivalent method

.

3. Amend the MainActivity

:-

```
public class test extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton btnadd; //??
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase; // NOT NEEDED
    DatabaseOpenHelper databaseHelper; // NOT NEEDED
    TextView yekuntxt; //??
    private ListView listView;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter; // ADDED
    Cursor cursor; // ADDED
    DatabaseAccess databaseAccess; // ADDED

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this); // Changed to use class variable
        databaseAccess.open();
        addSomeData(); // <<<< ADDED for testing (adds some data to the table (4 rows as below))
        cursor = databaseAccess.getDataAsCursor(); // ADDED
        //final List<String> costumer_data = databaseAccess.getData(); // REMOVED
        //databaseAccess.close(); // <<<<<<<<<< MUST NOT CLOSE DB WHEN using Cursor (see onDestory method)
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, // (show AD and SOYAD seprately)
                cursor, //<<<< The cursor used for the source data of the ListView
                new String[]{"AD","SOYAD"}, // The columns FROM which to get the data
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1, // The respective views TO which the data is placed
                        android.R.id.text2},
                0
        );
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent(test.this, activity_daxilet.class);
                    i.putExtra("ID", id);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< Added to close the Cursor  and then database when done with it
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        cursor.close();
        databaseAccess.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< Added to load some data for testing
    private void addSomeData() {
        databaseAccess.addRow("TestAD1","TestSOYAD1");
        databaseAccess.addRow("TestAD2","TestSOYAD2");
        databaseAccess.addRow("TestAD3","TestSOYAD3");
        databaseAccess.addRow("TestAD4","TestSOYAD4");
    }
}
```

- Comments should explain the changes made

.

4. Amend activity_daxilet.java to get the passed id

:-

```
public class activity_daxilet extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView showpassedid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daxilet);
        showpassedid = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.showpassedid);

        long passedid = this.getIntent().getLongExtra("ID",-1);
        showpassedid.setText("Id Passed was " + String.valueOf(passedid));
    }
}
```

5. Amend activity_daxilet.xml to include the TextView showpassedid

e.g. :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity_daxilet">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/showpassedid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

### Results

#### When first run :-

[image]

### Click on an Item (3) :-

[image]

Comment: First of all thanks for detailed explanation, it is too much usefull, but when I apply these codes it gives me error in:
      this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,  new String[]{"AD","SOYAD"},new 
      int[] ,android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},0); 

part. It says SimpleCursorAdapter() in SimpleCursorAdapter cannot be applied to there

Comment: you can see error from here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VlKQFeahZXZNU4Ux5QTlu-qr41CvuV3Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElnurHasanov you forgot about the cursor: `cursor, //<<<< The cursor used for the source data of the ListView`

Comment: @pskink thanks, error solved but when I run app it says it has stoped https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3E2joR9Myb1wjzpEeZyzCf_BsezP3g9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElnurHasanov check https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat

Comment: @pskink it says
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D3E2joR9Myb1wjzpEeZyzCf_BsezP3g9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ElnurHasanov the error is self describing: `column '_id' does not exist`

Comment: @ElnurHasanov it soundes like you didn't apply/use `String[] columns = new String[]{"AD","SOYAD","rowid AS " + BaseColumns._ID};` or didn't use the `getDataAsCursor()` method. As explained a Cursor Adapter REQUIRES a column named **_id** (the code creates such a column, unless you are using a table defined with WITHOUT ROWID).

Comment: now it says https://drive.google.com/file/d/195gl6_uy9lusX5WrZxwjAZ0T219CtKOS/view?usp=sharing 
name of column is ID in my database and because of that in BaseColumns.java
I changed
      public static final String _ID = "_id";

to

   public static final String _ID = "id";

Answer (score 0):

your sending the position of the `id` in the `listview`, what I think you want to pass to your second activity is the  `id`it self.

So change this line :

```
i.putExtra("ID", position);
```

with :

```
i.putExtra("ID", Id);
```

to retrieve your data in your second activity you should use instead of this :

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle !=null){
    ad.setText("@position");
}
```

this (also you need to find your textview by id) :

```
ad = findViewById(R.id.textviewid);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String Id = intent.getExtras().getString("ID");
ad.setText(Id);
```

you need to add an id to your `textview` if you didn't ! add this tag to your `textview` in the `xml` file :

```
android:id="@+id/textviewid"
```

and that should be it.

Comment: I changed it in main activity but it still gives me error, in second activity which method should I use to show data from main activity in textview ?

Comment: @ElnurHasanov so did you use `SimpleCursorAdapter` as i said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50834848/getting-id-of-item-from-database-when-item-from-listview-is-clicked#comment88675000_50834848)?

Comment: @user007 when I  when I click to listview to pass to second activity app stops working.Probably its because of  Bundle   
part

Comment: @ElnurHasanov I updated my answer check it out !! hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

- we could get the id when we are get costumer_data from database (**getData**), like: SELECT ID, ...
- pass it to the second view as an extra instead of currently set **position**

Good luck